# 0403-006 Execute permission denied

Tags: shell

I'm trying to 'cat' the text file inside my shell script program and facing below 
error.  What could be the problem?

Code:

`KILL_SWITCH=cat rtpSwitchFile.txt`

Error:

`0403-006 Execute permission denied.`

Comment: I tried by giving executable permission but still facing same issue:                                                                                                                                                                                                      chmod 777 *.*

Comment: What kind of shell, and what OS?

Comment: I'm running .sh shell script program. OS - Linux

Comment: Try `KILL_SWITCH="$(cat rtpSwitchFile.txt)"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use command substitution to put the contents of the file into a variable:

```
KILL_SWITCH=$(cat rtpSwitchFile.txt)
```

or in `bash/ksh93/zsh` you can also use:

```
KILL_SWITCH=$(< rtpSwitchFile.txt)
```

Comment: Your suggestion helped.  Thank you.